# Is extrinsic curvature a property of the manifold or the embedded surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Good day, to explain my question further, does changing the way we embed a surface into a manifold change its extrinsic curvature? Just getting exposed to these topics of differential geometry so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Extrinsic curvature is a property of both: it measures how  the surface bends due to the ambient geometry. It highly depends on the embedding

Comment: The curvature of the ambient manifold is relevant, too. Consider a round $2$-sphere embedded either in $\Bbb R^3$ or in $S^3$ (as a great sphere or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example is to take a paper sheet and draw straight lines on it. You can make a cylinder and a plane with it.

Depending on the direction you draw the lines, they are curves with non-zero curvature in the cylinder, while if you flatten it into a plane, these curves will have zero-curvature in the three dimensional space. In this case both are the same curves, under a transformation preserving distances since you do not stretch the paper.

So any extrinsic measure of curvature can depend on how we embed it on the manifold.